# how to use external dropdown for zoom values in stock highcharts

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

How can I use external dropdown for zoom-in zoom-out stock timeseries data ?

Initially when I get to the chart, on load, I display 1hour data which is fine. At this point, `internal or integrated dropdown's` other options are disabled as I load small range of data.

I have an `external dropdown` where I keep all the options that I need. I should be able to click any of the options and it should fetch relevant data from BE and update the chart.

***For some reason, it fetches the right data from BE but it doesn't update the chart***.

I really don't know how can I use `external dropdown` just like `internal or integrated dropdown`.

For some reason, let's say I don't want to use `internal dropdown` then how can I achieve these functionalities of `internal dropdown` for `external dropdown`. **is it even possible** ?

**My Efforts**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-pntth2?file=index.js,chartOptions.js,index.html

---

**Expectation**: It should work like internal dropdown selection. eg. click on '6 hours' value from external dropdown and all options of `internal dropdown` will be enabled. Then just check how `internal dropdown` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

1. Enable the `adaptToUpdatedData` option
2. Remove `navigator.series`
3. Call `chart.zoomOut()` at the end of the `afterSetExtremes` function

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-l7aasw?file=index.js

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.adaptToUpdatedData

Comment: amazing to see this is working. Thanks a lot for your help. You really have good knowledge on highcharts.